# combine the results obtained from two separate joins

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have three tables:
 `users`:

[image: users table]

`blog`

[image: blog table]

instagram

[image: instagram table]

I want to have results from inner join of (users and blog) and (users and instagram) together for which currently I am executing these query
1.)

```
SELECT instagram.post_author,instagram.post_link,instagram.post_image,instagram.ts,users.username 
from instagram 
INNER JOIN users ON instagram.access_key=users.access_key ORDER BY instagram.ts DESC
```

2.)

```
SELECT blog.content,users.username,blog.ts 
from blog 
INNER JOIN users ON blog.access_key=users.access_key ORDER BY blog.ts DESC
```

I want to combine results from both of these queries but I can't figure out how to.
p.s: `UNION` **can't** be operated as selected columns are different in number and compatibility.

Comment: How do you want them combined? Post expected results to clarify.

Comment: you and have more than one `INNER JOIN`

Comment: Join with both `instagram` and `blog`. You'll probably want to use `LEFT JOIN` so you get results for user that don't have both instagram and blog entries.

Comment: I want entries from both of the instagram and blog table with added mapped  column of username from user table.The results should finally be in descending order of timestamps 'ts' present in both instagram and blog table

Answer (score 0):

Join all 3 tables.

```
SELECT users.username, 
    instagram.post_author,instagram.post_link,instagram.post_image,instagram.ts AS instagram_ts, 
    blog.content,blog.ts AS blog_ts
from users 
LEFT JOIN instagram ON instagram.access_key=users.access_key 
LEFT JOIN blog ON blog.access_key=users.access_key
ORDER BY instagram.ts DESC
```

Use `LEFT JOIN` so you get `NULL` when there's no corresponding `blog` or `instagram` row for the user.

Answer (score 0):

I think you do want `union all`:

```
select uib.*
from ((select u.username, i.ts, i.post_author, i.post_link, i.post_image, 
              null as b.content
       from users u join
            instagram i
            on i.access_key = u.access_key
      ) union all
      (select u.username, b.ts, null as post_author, null as post_link, null as post_image, 
              b.content
       from users u join left join
            blog b
            on b.access_key = u.access_key
      )
     ) uib
order by ts desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can use the last timestamp from blog and instagram which have same access key.

```
select * from (
    SELECT blog.content, instagram.post_author, instagram.post_link, instagram.post_image, instagram.ts, users.username, if(instagram.ts > blog.ts, instagram.ts, blog.ts) ts
    from users
    INNER JOIN instagram ON instagram.access_key=users.access_key
    INNER JOIN blog ON blog.access_key=users.access_key
) t
order by ts desc
```